# Progress dialog wont show with async task

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

I have been searching for an answer for this for some time now. I have an async task that downloads the database needed for my app, while this is downloading my app cant do anything as all the data it references is in this file, i have the app waiting for the file to be downloaded but i am attempting to show a progress dialog so the user knows something is happening while they wait for this to happen.

my code is currently

```
public class fileDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, SQLiteDatabase> 
{
    private File dbFile;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory;

    public fileDownloader(Context c)
    {
        super();
        context = c;
    }
    @Override    
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {       
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Database...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected SQLiteDatabase doInBackground(Void... v) 
    {        
     ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SQLiteDatabase db1)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

however nothing shows up i have also tried directly calling ProgressDialog.show in the pre execute and moving this to the calling activity with no luck.

please help!

Comment: I have had another crack at solving this without success, i have even tried adding a toast to see if could get this to show and hav had no luck with this either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution to this was to look at the calling class the UI thread was getting blocked therefor the dialog never showed up.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't understand your solution.  How did you change things so that the UI thread is no longer getting blocked?

Comment: I agree with @ScottBiggs. Would you explain yourself a little more, please?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - how long does your `doInBackground` method run? Maybe your dialog is shown, but the time is just too fast for the dialog to show up...

Comment: it takes about 1 - 2 minutes atm so more then long enough for the dialog to pop up and be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine, I am using it:

```
private class DownloadHomeSectionData extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainScreen);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getResources()
                .getString(R.string.loading));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (HomeButton homeBtn : appDesigner.getHomeButtons()) {
            StorageManager.getInstance().downloadFileSyncronously(
                    homeBtn.getTab_logo_selected_image());
            StorageManager.getInstance().downloadFileSyncronously(
                    homeBtn.getTab_logo_unselected_image());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

In your case, I think you may be passing wrong context to `ProgressDialog`.